# How to chain/resolve promises using Rx.js?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming

Today, I was learning  some cool stuff and running through some examples with Rx.js. I totally understand Rx.js is an asynchronous programming library, and everything is treated as a first class collection.

Could anyone please explain me how to chain promises using Rx.js ??

Comment: Are you looking for `flatMap`? Alternatively, promises being promises, you can always use `then`.

Comment: yes, i need a snippet for resolving promises using the flatMap. Thank you so much.

Comment: What do you mean, "*I need a snippet*"? Please show us the code you have, where you create/get the promises, and how you want to have them combined.

Comment: Post an code example of what you want to do with promises and maybe someone could tell you have to achieve that with Rx.js